# What should be my file path so it can find my text file?

Tags: java

I'm creating a JAVA program to read a text file, but my function to open the file is not finding the file, this is my open and read file

```
public void openFile() {
    try {
        myReader = new Scanner(new File("C://Users//Desktop//CountInvTest1.txt"));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
}

public void readFile() {
    
    while(myReader.hasNextLine()) {
        
        String data = myReader.nextLine();
        System.out.printf(" ", data);
    }
    
}
```

I've changed the `myReader = new Scanner(new File("C://Users//Desktop//CountInvTest1.txt"));` to `myReader = new Scanner(new File("CountInvTest1.txt"));` and changed it to the path in the source folder in my project but still getting "File not found" from my try and catch. I've tried the file path with only one / but still the file is not found.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Noticed i got a -1 in my vote, was it the way I phrased the question? Should have been "What should be my path to find my text file?"

Comment: If you're using windows, the easy way (to ensure you don't have the wrong file path) is to shift + right-click on the file (in your case CountInvTest1.txt), and click "copy as path" in the context menu, then paste it back in. See if it makes a difference.

Comment: @leomarrg1 Are you sure the directory is `C:\Users\Desktop\ `? It looks like the username is missing.

Answer (score 2):

### Bad error handling

That is *atrocious* error handling. You should never do this: It's leading to this very question! The exception object (e) has a *ton* of useful information: It has a type (and not just 'IOException', it's probably, for example, a FileNotFoundException), it has a message, it has a cause, it has supressed exceptions, and it can have custom information (for example, SQLExceptions have SQL-specific error codes). You're throwing that *ALL* in the bin, just assuming it's a file not found issue (could be a file access issue, or a ton of other things), and printing no further info.

This is why you should essentially never write a catch block unless you:

1. actually handle it. Logging it and continuing is *not* handling  things, unless you're a framework catching problems in plugins. Which, as a beginner, you won't be doing.
2. end the catch block in a `throw` statement, adding the caught exception as a chain.

But mostly you should just 'throw it onwards'. Note that `psv main` can and should throw Exception.

Then you'll get all that information printed to the console, and you'll know if it is actually a file not found issue, or something else.

### Bad slashes

Backslashes (`\`) are the escape symbol in java strings, but they are also the default path separator in windows. As a consequence, if you use them in strings, you have to double them up. But you're using *forward* slashes. Java understands this even on windows, but you must not double them up. It's just `"C:\\Foo"` or `C:/Foo`, your choice, either works. But `C://Foo` does not.

### Sometimes, just trust what you are seeing

You're getting a file not found exception. That might possibly be because... the file was not found. Your path is `C://Users//Desktop`.. that's a bizarre path that probably doesn't exist. Perhaps you meant `C:/Users/leomarrg/Desktop`?

The user's home dir is `System.getProperty("user.home")`. So most likely you want:

```
Path p = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")).resolve("Desktop");
```

That's using the newer path API (you want it - it's got way better error handling). If you insist on sticking with the old and dusty, `new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the path, you are using 2 "/" when navigating though the folders, the correct path should be: `C:/Users/Desktop/CountInvTest1.txt`

Comment: Forgot to mention but I've used only one / and still getting the same error.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Hi and thanks for the reply, tried that but still nothing.